# Purge PHPVirtualbox to start over - has persistent settings/files somewhere

Tags: virtualbox, php

So I am diagnosing an error in PhpVirtualBox related to the console. My Vbox starts and gets to login screen then when I try to console in I get

```
Disconnect reason: E: TCP: SECURITY_ERROR Error #2048
```

I have tried everything I can think of, uninstalled Vbox, deleted vboxusers, uninstalled extpack to start fresh.

PhPVirtualBox does not get installed, it gets downloaded and served somewhere Apache can serve it from. But I notice if I delete the directory and place it back there, it somehow has my old User Names and Password still in its settings.

I need to delete all files related to PhPVirtualBox to start fresh on that front. Any thoughts on where to go?

Comment: anybody got any ideas?